# how to open two ports on Openshift 3.5

Tags: node.js, port, openshift

You can see at below code their are two ports (port1 and port2). It was running fine on old OpenShift (v2) but i can't run on newer version 3.5. How can i run this code on newer version. 
***port1 -- it is use for websocket,
port2 -- it is use for http POST request***
source : https://github.com/hayageek/WhatsApp-Web

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
var port1      = 8080;
var port2      = 8081;



var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var wss = new WebSocketServer({ path:'/gencode',port: port1,server:ip });


var clients = {};
var dumCounter=0;
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
    var obj = JSON.parse(message);
    if(obj.op == 'hello')
    {
        var uuidToken = uuid.v1();
        clients[uuidToken] = ws; 
        var hello = { op:'hello',token:uuidToken};
        ws.send(JSON.stringify(hello),{mask:false});
    }

  });

});



var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain","Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"});
    process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
             response.end("Exception");
    });
    if(request.method == "POST")
    {
        var url = request.url;
        if(url == "/auth")
        {

        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function(chunk) 
        {
                  body += chunk.toString();
        });

        request.on('end', function () {
        var params = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("Recived Params: "+JSON.stringify(params));
            var uuId = params.uuid;
            var accessToken = params.access_token;

            var msg = {'op':'authdone','accessToken':accessToken};
            if(clients[uuId] != undefined || clients[uuId] != null)
            {
                console.log("Before "+Object.size(clients));
                clients[uuId].send(JSON.stringify(msg),{mask:false});
                delete clients[uuId];
                console.log("After "+Object.size(clients));

                response.end('{"status":"OK"}');

            }
            else
            {
                response.end('{"status":"NOK"}');
            }

            });
        }
        else
        {
              response.end('{"status":"NOK"}');

        }
    }
    else
    {
         response.end("NOT Supported");
    }

}).listen(port2,ip);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open additional ports by editing your deployment configuration. Ive included a snippet below:

`"containers": [
              {
                "name": "whatapp-web",
                "ports": [
                  {
                    "containerPort": 8080
                  },
                  {
                    "containerPort": 8081
                  }
                ]`

You will then also need to edit the service which exposes this application. Another example snippet from the service definition:

`"ports": [
          {
            "name": "websocket",
            "port": 8080
          },
          {
            "name": "http",
            "port": 8081
          }
        ]`

Create routes as required to expose these endpoints to the internet

Comment: I'm really sorry i'm new on OpenShift so i don't have any idea about editing in deployment configuration and service. Can you help me here?

Comment: i'd try whatever you told me but nothing happened. **spec:
  ports:
    - name: 8080-tcp
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: 8081-http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081**

Comment: Yes if you are using the `oc` command line tool then in the project, run `oc get dc` and `oc edit dc XYZ` where XYZ is the deployment config name of the app you want to edit. Then do the same with `oc get svc` to edit the service. It looks like you may have edited the route already

Comment: i have two ports in service file. PORTS are:  8080/TCP, 8081/TCP. Still not working.

Comment: Have you also edited the deployment configuration to match the first code snippet?

Comment: Yes I'd make change in deployent config file. If you can share your email id I'll send you screenshots

Comment: @AtulSingh can you share yours and I will reach out to you

Comment: atulsingh0401@gmail.com @user2983542